# check if condition met for a time duration python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to find if some conditions are met for a duration of time. My data look like the following:

| Datetime | Valve1 | Valve2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 11:00:01 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 11:00:15 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 11:30:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 11:30:45 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 12:00:10 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 12:15:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 01/01/2020 12:15:30 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 12:16:45 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 13:17:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 13:20:15 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 13:21:30 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 13:45:08 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/01/2020 14:00:00 | 0 | 1 |
| 01/01/2020 14:01:15 | 0 | 1 |
| 01/01/2020 14:30:00 | 0 | 1 |

And my condition:
(Valve1=1 for 1h) and (Valve-0 for 1h)
I thought of using rolling sum as below:

```
data = data.set_index('Datetime', drop=True)
data.loc[((data.Valve1.rolling('1h').sum())==?) & ((data.Valve2.rolling('1h').sum())==0), 'alarm'] = 'Yes'
```

The final dataframe should not be resampled or include any interpolated/ filled values.
[Note]: any missing datetime got the same valve1 and valve2 of the previous available datetime

The final result looks like the following:

| Datetime | Valve1 | Valve2 | Alarm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 11:00:01 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 01/01/2020 11:00:15 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 01/01/2020 11:30:00 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 01/01/2020 11:30:45 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 01/01/2020 12:00:10 | 1 | 0 | Yes |
| 01/01/2020 12:15:00 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 01/01/2020 12:15:30 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 01/01/2020 12:16:45 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 01/01/2020 13:17:00 | 1 | 0 | Yes |
| 01/01/2020 13:20:15 | 1 | 0 | Yes |
| 01/01/2020 13:21:30 | 1 | 0 | Yes |
| 01/01/2020 13:45:08 | 1 | 0 | Yes |
| 01/01/2020 14:00:00 | 0 | 1 |  |
| 01/01/2020 14:01:15 | 0 | 1 |  |
| 01/01/2020 14:30:00 | 0 | 1 |  |

Comment: Why do you need to not use resampling and missing datetime values?

Comment: What I mean is not to increase/decrease the size of the dataframe, as the dataframe will be visualized I want to visualize the original not a resampled one

Comment: why no **alarm** for 11am?

Comment: 11am is the first data point I need to check if  valve1 between [10am-11am] is always 1 and valve2 between [10am-11am] is always 0, but I don't have any data before 11 am

Comment: I guess that he's trying to check the conditions of the last 1 hour for each record.

Comment: yes exactly I need to check the condition for the last 1 hour for each record

Comment: the last "1 hour" is **14:00** in this data then,  so no alarms for any other hours.  do you really mean previous?  i.e. comparing hour by hour,  not within the hour

Comment: For example, I got a row with datetime 13:16:00, I will check between 12:16:00 and 13:16:00 if the conditions are met. Any missing datetime got the same valve1 and valve2 of the previous row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you could not resample your data, you can do so as below;

```
>>> temp_df = pd.concat([df.copy().iloc[0, :].to_frame().T, df.copy()], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
# added this line to add initialization effect
>>> temp_df.loc[0, ['Valve1', 'Valve2']] = [0, 1]
>>> temp_df['alarm'] = temp_df.Valve1.eq(1) & temp_df.Valve2.eq(0)
>>> df['alarm'] = temp_df.set_index('Datetime').rolling('1h').agg({'alarm': pd.Series.product}).replace({1: 'Yes', 0: 'No'})[1:].values
>>> df

              Datetime  Valve1  Valve2 alarm
0  2020-01-01 11:00:01       1       0    No
1  2020-01-01 11:00:15       1       0    No
2  2020-01-01 11:30:00       1       0    No
3  2020-01-01 11:30:45       1       0    No
4  2020-01-01 12:00:10       1       0   Yes
5  2020-01-01 12:15:00       1       1    No
6  2020-01-01 12:15:30       1       0    No
7  2020-01-01 12:16:45       1       0    No
8  2020-01-01 13:17:00       1       0   Yes
9  2020-01-01 13:20:15       1       0   Yes
10 2020-01-01 13:21:30       1       0   Yes
11 2020-01-01 13:45:08       1       0   Yes
12 2020-01-01 14:00:00       0       1    No
13 2020-01-01 14:01:15       0       1    No
14 2020-01-01 14:30:00       0       1    No
```

That should work now.

Comment: Thank you but valve1 should be eq to 1 for an hour and valve2 should be eq to 0 for an hour. please have a look at the updated data and results table

Comment: Oh I got it. Then let me just adjust my answer.

Comment: ok I got it we can use rolling.product and eliminate the wrong result of the first row by adding a row not satisfying the condition

Comment: Correct, that's exactly what I did :)

Answer (score 0):

- use `groupby()` **date()** and **hour**
- use logic to give **bool** result
- `merge()` back to your dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Datetime    Valve1  Valve2
01/01/2020 11:00:01 1   0
01/01/2020 11:00:15 1   0
01/01/2020 11:30:00 1   0
01/01/2020 11:30:45 1   0
01/01/2020 12:00:10 1   1
01/01/2020 12:15:00 1   1
01/01/2020 12:15:30 1   1
01/01/2020 12:16:45 0   1
01/01/2020 13:17:00 1   0
01/01/2020 13:20:15 1   0
01/01/2020 13:21:30 1   0
01/01/2020 13:45:08 1   0
01/01/2020 14:00:00 0   1
01/01/2020 14:01:15 0   1
01/01/2020 14:30:00 0   1
"""), sep="\t")

df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)

dfr = df.groupby([df.Datetime.dt.date, df.Datetime.dt.hour]).apply(lambda dfa: ((dfa.Valve1==1) & (dfa.Valve1==1)).all())

df = (df.merge(dfr.to_frame(), left_on=[df.Datetime.dt.date, df.Datetime.dt.hour], right_index=True)
 .drop(columns=["key_0","key_1"])
 .rename(columns={0:"Cond"})
)
```

|  | Datetime | Valve1 | Valve2 | Cond |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 11:00:01 | 1 | 0 | True |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 11:00:15 | 1 | 0 | True |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 11:30:00 | 1 | 0 | True |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 11:30:45 | 1 | 0 | True |
| 4 | 2020-01-01 12:00:10 | 1 | 1 | False |
| 5 | 2020-01-01 12:15:00 | 1 | 1 | False |
| 6 | 2020-01-01 12:15:30 | 1 | 1 | False |
| 7 | 2020-01-01 12:16:45 | 0 | 1 | False |
| 8 | 2020-01-01 13:17:00 | 1 | 0 | True |
| 9 | 2020-01-01 13:20:15 | 1 | 0 | True |
| 10 | 2020-01-01 13:21:30 | 1 | 0 | True |
| 11 | 2020-01-01 13:45:08 | 1 | 0 | True |
| 12 | 2020-01-01 14:00:00 | 0 | 1 | False |
| 13 | 2020-01-01 14:01:15 | 0 | 1 | False |
| 14 | 2020-01-01 14:30:00 | 0 | 1 | False |